# Is there a swiftc compiler optimization to remove unnecessary large variables?

Tags: swift, compiler-optimization

When I'm writing code with higher-order functions, I find it to be a lot cleaner to write out the expressions one transformation at a time like so:

```
let children = objects.map { $0.children }
let validChildren = children.filter { $0.isValid }
let sortedChildren = validChildren.sorted { $0.count < $1.count }
```

However, I know that each of these functions returns a new Array object that I'm storing into a variable, so in theory I'm creating and holding on to a new Array each time and wasting a lot of memory. It would be better to write the call as one line so that the unnecessary Arrays are destroyed after use.

```
let sortedChildren = objects.map { $0.children } .filter { $0.isValid } .sorted { $0.count < $1.count }
```

But this is a lot more annoying to read later on since there's so much going on in one line of code. So my question is: Does Swift's compiler have an optimization to forgive my nit-pickiness and remove the unused variables at compile time?

Comment: *"there's so much going on in one line of code"* – Note that you can break the line before `.filter` and before `.sorted` ...

Comment: This smells like premature optimization.

Comment: No the compiler wont care about you splitting it up in to different variables. But if you worry about memory you can do as @MartinR said and use line-breaks, or you could at least declare your variables as private / fileprivate or lazy for that matter.

Comment: Also arrays are "copy-on-write" which makes unmodified copies "cheap". – Did you profile if there is really a difference between your two versions?

Comment: @MartinR Of course, but this would still qualify as a single instruction and be a lot noisier than the first option. But my question is primarily about compiler optimization. I'm unsure of swiftc's available features considering it's relatively young age.

Comment: @rmaddy When you're dealing with a huge array, the difference between 1000 objects of memory and 5000 objects is an absolutely necessary optimization.

Comment: @MartinR On Linux, so no easy access to Xcode profiler. I figured it would be an easily answered yes/no question, so I asked. The copy-on-write seems to answer it though, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was mentioned by @MartinR in the question comments, but deserved an official answer and a source.

[As per the Swift repository docs:](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#enabling-optimizations)

> All standard library containers in Swift are value types that use COW
>   (copy-on-write) [4] to perform copies instead of explicit copies. In
>   many cases this allows the compiler to elide unnecessary copies by
>   retaining the container instead of performing a deep copy. This is
>   done by only copying the underlying container if the reference count
>   of the container is greater than 1 and the container is mutated. For
>   instance in the following, no copying will occur when d is assigned to
>   c, but when d undergoes structural mutation by appending 2, d will be
>   copied and then 2 will be appended to d:

```
var c: [Int] = [ ... ]
var d = c        // No copy will occur here.
d.append(2)      // A copy *does* occur here.
```

As higher-order functions do not modify the object they are called upon, it can be said with high confidence that results are optimized for size.

Answer (score 1):

There is no different between two versions.

Even if you don't assign the result to a variable, one new instance of the list will be created in order to store the result of the function call. Hence, the memory usage is the same.

```
objects.map { $0.children }.filter { $0.isValid }.sorted { $0.count < $1.count }
```

So after each function call, we still need memory to store the result of that function no matter if you `assign` it to the variable or not. And `assigning` to another variable doesn't make any copy of the object.